# submit form using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms

javascript:

```
$("#id_report").on('change', function() {
   var reportform = document.getElementById("status-form");
   var live = document.getElementById("id_report");
   if (live.checked == true){
    reportform.submit();
   }
  });
```

forms.py

```
class Reportform(Form):
    report = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(),required=False, label="Report",initial=True)
```

template.html

```
<form action="." id="status-form" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  <p>{{closedreport.report}}Show Reports</p>
  </form>
```

I want to submit the form if check box is checked.By default the check box is checked,but form is not getting submitted.

Comment: 'By default the check box is checked', so you want to submit the form instantly?

Comment: @user2086641 and why on earth would you like to do that? :D Maybe you are trying to achieve something that can be done in a much simpler and more logiacl.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#id_report").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'){
        $("#status-form").submit();
    }
});
```

When the button is clicked, the script checks if checkbox is checked. If it is, submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

To submit your form instantly (and i'm guessing you want to have that happen when the page where your form is on loads) you could do :

```
// Wait for document to load
$(function(){
    // Check if your checkbox is indeed checked
    if($('#id_report').is(':checked'){
        // Submit the form
        $("#status-form").submit();
    }
});
```

Or you could do it like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#status-form").on('change', '#id_report', function() {
        var reportform = document.getElementById("status-form");
        var live = document.getElementById("id_report");
        if (live.checked == true){
            reportform.submit();
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```